# EVO Hurricane Bicycle Pumps - how to remove the plunger?

Tags: pump

Most bicycle pumps have screws or twist off the top to remove the plunger, but these Evo Hurricane pumps have a very odd collar with no embedded screws unlike others (see below).

[image: EVO Hurricane Bicycle Pump]

Anybody know the proper way to get the plunger out without destroying the pump?

Comment: Can you see any traces of adhesive in the seam?  It might be glued shut, or ultrasonically welded.   If so, it may be disposable.   Do you need to open it at all?

Comment: I don't think so.  It seems to be two separate pieces actually which are somehow locked in together.  There are two tiny holes on the side, not screw holes though, I almost think I should try using something like a watch opening tool to get the bottom part to twist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out.  The two small pin holes on the collar was the clue.  It has hidden plastic locking tabs!  To release, both tabs covered by the lower collar need to be pushed in at the same time as you pull up on the collar. Here's a picture of it once I got it off: [image: EVO Bicycle Pump plunger collar]

There probably is a special tool made to do this, as the tabs are pretty strong but the holes in the collar just pinholes!  I used two flathead screwdrivers instead, wedging them in under the collar to push in the plastic tabs.

Comment: Nice answer. Just be careful when doing this with the screwdrivers because if you slip (and I can imagine it would be possible) you can hurt yourself (or a close observer) pretty bad. A puncture wound would be bad.

Comment: Awesome work!   I'd not have guessed this.  Remember to mark this answer as "accepted" too.